# How to create dotted border with round dots in WebKit browsers?

Tags: html, css, webkit, border

In WebKit driven browsers, e.g. Safari, Chrome, borders with their style declared as `dotted` are rendered with square dots instead of round.

Is there any way to force rendering of round dots seamlessly across browsers?

#### Reference Test

- [on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e5VK6/)

Comment: 2023, every major browser supports it. Wait. Did anyone mention Safari?

Answer (score 28):

A natively supported solution is currently lacking, as [the specification does not define these properties explicitly](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#propdef-border-style), and leaves it for the browser's implementation.

You may, however, use SVG to create the border, as it offers full control over the characteristics you're after.

Draw a line, than define its `stroke-dasharray` and `stroke-linecap` attributes to achieve the desired effect.

#### Example Code Snippet

```svg
<line 
    x1="40" x2="260" 
    y1="100" y2="100" 
    stroke="#5184AF" 
    stroke-width="20" 
    stroke-linecap="round" 
    stroke-dasharray=".001, 30" />
```

#### Result Snapshot

[image: SVG dotted round border]

#### Demo

- http://jsfiddle.net/eliranmal/hsfxS/

#### References (on Mozilla Developer Network)

- [`stroke-dasharray`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/SVG/Attribute/stroke-dasharray)
- [`stroke-linecap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/SVG/Attribute/stroke-linecap)

Comment: glad you loved it, @zoltar.

Comment: I created a circle with circles as the border using this approach. The [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Zeaklous/75WsM/5/) may be useful for someone

Comment: nice one, @ZachSaucier, it demonstrates the flexibility of this approach.

Comment: Very awesome implementation of rounded borders. :D

Comment: This doesn't produce fully round dots on smaller sizes. The solution is to change `stroke-dasharray` to ".001, 30" (found the solution in @ZachSaucier 's fiddle)

Comment: @Rijk - awesome, it makes sense. i'll update the answer accordingly

Answer (score 4):

I also had this problem but I only needed three round dots under my menu item. 
So I just used a terrible hack, but it worked:
First of all I hooked in FontAwesome using @import
Then added the round dot characters as content in the CSS:

```css
#nav ul .current_page_item a:after {
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';
    content: "\f111  \f111  \f111";
    font-size: 6px;
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: great hack :) nice use of `content`

Answer (score 0):

Based on [ozbassplayer's solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24815934/2686510) (thank you).

How to use in **sass** to generate longer lines without needing of counting dots.

Only found dissadvantage is cutting of dots when line is not 'ideally' long.

```
  &:after {
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';  
    display: block;  
    font-size: 6px;  

  
    letter-spacing: 3px;      // to adjust space between dots
    white-space: nowrap;      // force to keep in one line  
    overflow: hidden;         // avoid rendering dots out of container
    width: 100%;

    $content: ' ';
    @for $i from 1 through 50 {
      $content: $content + " \f111";
    }

    content: $content;
  }
```