# css dotted hr is set of little square not dots/cricles

Tags: css, dotted-line

Here's the part I added to my CSS style sheet in the header:

```
<style>

    body{
      background-color: #EAF6F6;
    }

    hr{
border-style: none;
border-top-style: dotted;
border-color: lightgrey;
border-width: 5px;
width: 5%;
    }

  </style>
```

And here's what it looks like:

[image]

As you can see, it more looks like squares than rounded shapes like dots and the tutorial I was following had the exact same piece of code but ended up with tiny dots in a line a.k.a dotted line! Why is that?

Comment: It looks fine at my end as well, please create an snippet and show us the issue

Comment: It depends how your browser decides to render a dotted border. Some may use dots. Some may use squares. Some may use chickens. It's out of your control.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dotted lines are being rendered differently depending on the browser and the operating system. I quickly ran a test with multiple browser on multiple systems.

The following browsers render square dots:

- Safari MacOS
- Safari iOS
- Chrome iOS

[image]

The following browsers render round dots:

- Chrome MacOS
- Chrome Windows
- Firefox MacOS
- Firefox Windows
- Edge Windows

[image]

Here is a thread that gives you alternative solutions, such as using images, SVGs or fonts to achieve a consistent look through out all browsers. [How to create dotted border with round dots in WebKit browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11280676/how-to-create-dotted-border-with-round-dots-in-webkit-browsers)

Answer (score -2):

```
<hr class="class-1" />     
.class-1 {
border: 5px dotted #000;
border-color: red;
}
```

Try to include this class in your hr tag